# Kivy+mqtt-When on_message,Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, mqtt, paho

I'm using kivy 1.11.0 with python 2.7.15.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string("""
<InitScreen>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x:"center"
        anchor_y:"center"
        Label:
            text:"init"
<WaitScreen>:
    Image:
        id:charactor
        pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'y':0 }
        size_hint:1,1
        source:'./wait1.png'
""")

class Charactor(Image):
    pass
class InitScreen(Screen):
    pass
class WaitScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WaitScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class View(App):
    sm = ScreenManager()
    cli = mqtt.Client(protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(View, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        self.sm.add_widget(InitScreen(name='init'))
        self.sm.current='init'
        return self.sm

    def on_start(self):
        self.cli.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.cli.on_message = self.on_message
        self.cli.connect('localhost', port=1883, keepalive=60)
        self.cli.loop_start()

    def on_connect(self,client, userdata, flags, respons_code):
        print('status {0}'.format(respons_code))
        client.subscribe('get/test')

    def on_message(self,client, userdata, msg):
        self.changeScreen()

    def changeScreen(self,**kwargs):
        self.sm.add_widget(WaitScreen(name='wait'))
        self.sm.current='wait'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    View().run()
```

if get message(on_message), change screen

but error happed

```
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
```

i think detected the cause of error
 have Image. 
When on_message load Image source, error happened
I think paho.mqtt callback(on_message,on_connect） is doubtful

because When self.changeScreen() is in　def on_start,def build, error not happened

below code is error has not happened

```
class View(App):
    sm = ScreenManager()
    cli = mqtt.Client(protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)
    waitflag = False
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(View, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        self.sm.add_widget(InitScreen(name='init'))
        self.sm.current='init'
        return self.sm

    def on_start(self):
        self.cli.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.cli.on_message = self.on_message
        self.cli.connect('localhost', port=1883, keepalive=60)
        self.cli.loop_start()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.changeScreen, 1) 

    def on_connect(self,client, userdata, flags, respons_code):
        print('status {0}'.format(respons_code))
        client.subscribe('get/test')

    def on_message(self,client, userdata, msg):
        self.waitflag = True

    def changeScreen(self,dt):
        if self.waitflag:
            self.sm.add_widget(WaitScreen(name='wait'))
            self.sm.current='wait'
            self.waitflag = False
```

but this code feel bad.because if WaitScreen don't use Image source, error not happened

Please tell me how to avoid errors.
i want to use upper code

Comment: Did you post the same code twice? I'm not willing to diff it to make sure. Please clarify or edit your question.

Comment: uppper code is no clock, below code is use clock

Comment: Explain the change rather than post dozens of identical lines. And please clarify the terms "doubtful" and "feel bad" - IT is not really feelings-related.

Comment: @3tori  `"port=1883"` or `port=1883`

Answer (score 1):

this question is got settled.

```
from kivy.clock import mainthread
```

and

```
@mainthread
def on_message(self,client, userdata, msg):
```

that's all

Comment: This doesn't actually explain what you changed or why it fixed the problem. Please add more context and then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem - SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)

The root cause is loading image i.e. your application is waiting until the image is loaded.

## Note

Replacing `Image` with `AsyncImage` will prevents your application from waiting until the image is loaded. But after loading 4 to 5 images/WaitScreen, it will crash with `IndexError: list index out of range`.

## Solution

1. Manually call Paho MQTT loop() method in Python script.
2. Added `number` of `NumericProperty` type because screen's name must be unique within a ScreenManager.

Please refer to the snippet, example, and output for details. In the examples, we use an online broker like the one at `iot.eclipse.org`.

### Snippet

```
def on_start(self):
    self.number = 0
    self.cli = mqtt.Client(protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)
    self.cli.on_connect = self.on_connect
    self.cli.on_message = self.on_message
    self.cli.connect("iot.eclipse.org", port=1883, keepalive=60)
    Clock.schedule_interval(self.loop, 0.5)    # call loop every 0.5 seconds

def loop(self, dt):
    # manually call the Paho MQTT loop() method
    self.cli.loop(0.1)  # blocks for 100 ms
```

[Screen » name](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen.name)

> ```
> name
> ```
>
> Name of the screen which ***must be unique*** within a ScreenManager.
>   This is the name used for ScreenManager.current.
>
> name is a StringProperty and defaults to ‘’.

## Example

### main.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

Builder.load_string("""
<InitScreen>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x:"center"
        anchor_y:"center"
        Label:
            text:"init"

<WaitScreen>:
    Image:
        id: charactor
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.5, 'y':0}
        size_hint: 1, 1
        source: './wait.jpeg'
""")


class Charactor(Image):
    pass


class InitScreen(Screen):
    pass


class WaitScreen(Screen):
    pass


class View(App):

    def build(self):
        self.number = NumericProperty(0)
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        self.sm.add_widget(InitScreen(name='init'))
        return self.sm

    def on_start(self):
        self.number = 0
        self.cli = mqtt.Client(protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)
        self.cli.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.cli.on_message = self.on_message
        self.cli.connect("iot.eclipse.org", port=1883, keepalive=60)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.loop, 0.5)   # call loop every 0.5 seconds

    def loop(self, dt):
        # manually call the Paho MQTT loop() method
        self.cli.loop(0.1)  # blocks for 100 ms

    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, response_code):
        print("\non_connect:")
        print("\tclient={0}, userdata={1}, flags={2}, response_code={3}".format(client, userdata, flags, response_code))
        client.subscribe("$SYS/#")

    def on_message(self, client, userdata, msg):
        print("\non_message:")
        print("\tclient={0}, userdata={1}, msg={2}".format(client, userdata, msg))
        print("\tmsg.topic={0}, msg.payload={1}".format(msg.topic, msg.payload))
        self.changeScreen()
        self.number += 1

    def changeScreen(self):
        print("\nchangeScreen:")
        print("\tnumber={}".format(self.number))
        screen_name = 'wait{}'.format(self.number)
        print("\tscreen_name={}".format(screen_name))

        self.sm.add_widget(WaitScreen(name=screen_name))
        self.sm.current = screen_name

    def on_stop(self):
        # stop the loop before exit
        self.cli.loop_stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    View().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01]